# Is arr.__len__() the preferred way to get the length of an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, methods

In [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), is the following the only way to get the number of elements?

```
arr.__len__()
```

If so, why the strange syntax?

Comment: I added an explanation about it at [Why is Python's `len` function faster than the `__len__` method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69563793/30038)

Answer (score 1256, accepted):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
len(my_list)
# 5
```

The same works for tuples:

```
my_tuple = (1,2,3,4,5)
len(my_tuple)
# 5
```

And strings, which are really just arrays of characters:

```
my_string = 'hello world'
len(my_string)
# 11
```

It was [intentionally done this way](https://web.archive.org/web/20200627113910/http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-does-python-use-methods-for-some-functionality-e-g-list-index-but-functions-for-other-e-g-len-list.htm) so that lists, tuples and other container types or iterables didn't all need to explicitly implement a public `.length()` method, instead you can just check the `len()` of anything that implements the 'magic' `__len__()` method.

Sure, this may seem redundant, but length checking implementations can vary considerably, even within the same language. It's not uncommon to see one collection type use a `.length()` method while another type uses a `.length` property, while yet another uses `.count()`. Having a language-level keyword unifies the entry point for all these types. So even objects you may not consider to be lists of elements could still be length-checked.  This includes strings, queues, trees, etc.

The functional nature of `len()` also lends itself well to functional styles of programming.

```
lengths = map(len, list_of_containers)
```

Comment: len() is a global, builtin function; __len__() is a method that object can implement.  len(foo) usually ends up calling foo.__len__().

Comment: @BT: I suspect at least part of the reason for `__len__` vs. `.length()` is that all names that begin and end with double-underscores (dunders) are: 1) Reserved for language use, and 2) Allow the language to bypass normal lookup rules (e.g. the method can be looked up directly on the instance's class w/o checking if the instance has shadowed it with an attribute of the same name). The CPython reference interpreter makes use of #2 to speed up implicit invocation of special methods (doesn't have to go through `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__`, doesn't have to check the instance `dict`, etc.).

Comment: In compiled languages this doesn't matter so much, but in an already slow, highly dynamic interpreted language, having core concepts that are used frequently defined in ways that allow them to be optimized better is important. The concept of length is tied to truthiness too, so it comes up when you do `if seq:`; CPython can optimize that to a C lookup through a couple pointers in C structs for `tp_bool`, then if it's not defined, looking up `tp_len`, calling it to get a raw C signed `size_t`, and checking if the result is `0` or non-zero.

Comment: Using `.length()` would either reserve a non-reserved name to mean length and apply optimizations to a name that is, on its surface, no different from any other, or not perform such reservations and optimizations, require `if seq.length():` explicitly, and involve multiple `dict` lookups, bound method construction, and creation of Python level `int`s (not merely C level signed `size_t`s) even for built-ins, making a simple "is it empty or non-empty?" test substantially slower (a quick test put it at over 4x longer to call a `length` method as part of a test, vs. just `if seq:`).

Answer (score 54):

The way you take a length of anything for which that makes sense (a list, dictionary, tuple, string, ...) is to call `len` on it.

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
s = 'abcde'
len(l) #returns 4
len(s) #returns 5
```

The reason for the "strange" syntax is that internally python translates `len(object)` into `object.__len__()`. This applies to any object. So, if you are defining some class and it makes sense for it to have a length, just define a `__len__()` method on it and then one can call `len` on those instances.

Answer (score 26):

Just use `len(arr)`:

```
>>> import array
>>> arr = array.array('i')
>>> arr.append('2')
>>> arr.__len__()
1
>>> len(arr)
1
```

Answer (score 24):

The preferred way to get the length of any python object is to pass it as an argument to the `len` function.  Internally, python will then try to call the special `__len__` method of the object that was passed.

Answer (score 24):

Python uses [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): it doesn't care about what an object *is*, as long as it has the appropriate interface for the situation at hand. When you call the built-in function len() on an object, you are actually calling its internal __len__ method. A custom object can implement this interface and len() will return the answer, even if the object is not conceptually a sequence.

For a complete list of interfaces, have a look here: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

Answer (score 8):

you can use `len(arr)` 
as suggested in previous answers to get the length of the array. In case you want the dimensions of a 2D array you could use `arr.shape` returns height and width

Answer (score 7):

`len(list_name)` function takes  list as a parameter and it calls list's `__len__()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Python suggests users use `len()` instead of `__len__()` for consistency, just like other guys said. However, There're some other benefits:

For some built-in types like `list`, `str`, `bytearray` and so on, the Cython implementation of `len()` takes a shortcut. It directly returns the `ob_size` in a C structure, which is faster than calling `__len__()`.

If you are interested in such details, you could read the book called "Fluent Python" by Luciano Ramalho. There're many interesting details in it, and may help you understand Python more deeply.