# count items in an object python

Tags: python

When I print the object I get:
    {'ip': 'ip', 'ip1': 'hi'}

But if I try to print the length of that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print len(options)
AttributeError: Values instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

I just need to know how many items are in that object (which appears to just be a dictionary).

Here is the whole code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from inspect import getmembers
from optparse import OptionParser



parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-a', '--allow',
    action="store", dest="ip",
    help="query string", default="spam")

parser.add_option('-d', '--deny',
    action="store", dest="ip1",
    help="query string", default="spam")


options, args = parser.parse_args()

print 'Query string:', options.ip
print 'Query string:', options.ip1

count=0
for i in options:
  count+=1
print count

if 1:
  print "Max number of options 1"
  exit
```

Comment: Downvoted because you forgot to add the related code useful for us to debug it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the length of an array in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518021/getting-the-length-of-an-array-in-python)

Comment: `options` seems to be an instance of some `Values` class, which has not implemented a `__len__` method.

Answer (score 1):

`options` is not a dictionary. It is a `Values` object which is one of the components of the return value of the `parse_args()` method.

In your code sample above, note how you use `options.ip` instead of `options['ip']`. What look like dict keys are thus being stored as instance variables of the object `options`. As such, they can be retrieved as a dictionary using the `vars()` function:

```
d = vars(options)
print len(d)
```

If you look at the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/optparse.py), you'll see that the `Values` class doesn't implement `__len__` but it *does* implemement `__str__`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.__dict__)
```

(lines 843-844 in the linked-to source)

That is what you see when you use `print options`, and `__dict__` is what is returned by the `vars()` function.